# factorygirl association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an ad factory but how to assign it to user.ads attribute? i've tried

```
@ad = user.ads.build(:ad)
```

but that didn't work for me

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :user do
  name     "My"
  email    "my@example.com"
 end

 factory :ad do
  title "Ola"
  description "Hello"
  user
 end
end


let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
#so i don't type it like this:
@ad = user.ads.build(title: "Lorem ipsum",description: "Lorem ipsum")
subject { @ad }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }    
5.times { FactoryGirl.create(:ad, user: user) }

user.ads #=> array of ads
```

Of course it'll will work only if you setup the associations in the `User` and `Ad` models appropriately.